# Infer type for multiple properties to be the same

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in Typescript to infer multiple properties to be the same type, or maybe infer the types based on a specific property..

Lets say we have ->

```js
interface Test<T> {
  value1: T;
  value2: T;
}

const test1:Test<string> = {
    value1: 'string1',
    value2: 'string1'
}
```

In the above if I made value1 or value2 into a number it would error, great.  But it would be nice to remove the generic `<string>` and for it to work out it's based on maybe the first property types `value1`.

At first I thought I could use a default for T as any, and it would then later infer the type, but it just keeps as any, as can be seen below we have a string and a number.

```
interface Test<T = any> {
  value1: T;
  value2: T;
}

const test1:Test = {
    value1: 'string1',
    value2: 2
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very difficult due to typescript inferring union types, so it'll infer `string | number` to make it work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you saw, a [generic type parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) doesn't have the effect you intend.  If you refer to the type as `Test` without specifying the type parameter as in `Test<string>`, the compiler will use the default and interpret it as `Test<any>`.  It will not *infer* `string` for you.  There is a feature request, [microsoft/TypeScript#10671](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571), asking for a way to have the compiler infer unspecified type parameters... something like `Test<infer>` or `Test<*>`. But so far TypeScript does not have this feature.

Instead what you can do is create a generic utility function which returns its input:

```
const asTest = <T,>(test: Test<T>) => test;
```

When you call a generic function, TypeScript will try to infer an appropriate type for a test parameter.  You can call this function instead of annotating the variable:

```
const testString = asTest({
  value1: "string1",
  value2: "string2"
})
// const testString: Test<string>

const testStringNumber = asTest({
  value1: "string1",
  value2: 2 // error! 'number' is not assignable to 'string'
})
// const testString: Test<string>
```

This behaves as desired.

---

Do note though that it's not always obvious whether the compiler will reject a value or synthesize a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) for its type parameter.  In `testStringNumber` it would have been reasonable for `T` to be inferred as `string | number`, but the heuristic the compiler uses is that people don't generally want to infer unions of primitive types.

On the other hand, the following code causes a union to be inferred:

```
const testUnion = asTest({
  value1: { a: "" },
  value2: { b: "" }
})
/* Test<{
    a: string;
    b?: undefined;
} | {
    b: string;
    a?: undefined;
}> */
```

That type, `Test<{a: string; b?: undefined} | {b: string; a?: undefined}>` does accurately describe the type of the value passed in to `asTest()`. The compiler's heuristic assumes that unions of object types are more acceptable and expected.

---

But perhaps you'd have preferred something that complains about such unions, and uses only (say) `value1` to infer `T`, and then just checks `value2` against it.  That is, you'd like the `T` in `value2` to be a *non-inferential type parameter usage* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  There is no official direct support for this, but there are some reasonable ways to simulate it.  For example:

```
const asTest = <T, U extends T>(test: { value1: T, value2: U }): Test<T> => test;
```

This version of `asTest` uses two generic type parameters; `T` for `value1`, and `U` for `value2`.  `U` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be assignable to `T`, so the compiler will only accept inputs where `value2` has a type that can be assigned to `value1`.  And the compiler will only infer `T` by looking at `value1` and not at `value2`.  It works the same for `testString` and `testStringNumber`:

```
const testString = asTest({ value1: "string1", value2: "string2" });
// const testString: Test<string>

const testStringNumber = asTest({
  value1: "string1",
  value2: 2 // error! 'number' is not assignable to 'string'
})
// const testString: Test<string>
```

But now `testUnion` produces an error:

```
const testUnion = asTest({
  value1: { a: "" },
  value2: { b: "" } // error! '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to '{ a: string; }'
})
```

because `{b: ""}` cannot be assigned to the type `{a: string}` as inferred from `value1`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA1CAnKBLA9sAjEgN4BQJSSWwALhgGYLIAq01APEwHzHkVIBuIADYBXCPgBcSJgG5eFQaIgAmKbN4BfMhXh4o1JLX2TprNvvRUA5twC8PPgOFiTAcgvX8rgDTynS1SR3aktgKy9NbSRdYH0kECgWOPsOb04ACiNqNTMuAEokW24suV4YuKyAZRDrQvjE1nTSR0UXKQAiDzD8dt8W5xUOrqtlds083gB6Sei9AyqasJz9c0WbKPL51mrQqwA5ETAAIww6hKTqJr9W8SG1nr6+G8DlJGmkDHQcdABCIOBDid0K5KFAkMAcAYEtgrKAjkJkNQcIYAJ4wZDBXaucZTGabQzbNbLdjDTgbOYE-QAVWAuGAZwa+iu-SUJiI8Q67SQGkeCgGgXZR053JxFEmACpTCtmo4OUhhnJZUgjgB+KQiYAAEwgdCoEE1iu5SAAPg5ZUL5WtDY4QGqkBrtbrgPrDRpuOLJmQtGRQJBYIxUBhsHhXqReFRaOgGIgpewuGa+ay1Nb-GJAuoKN6dBSsiYLqtdnYE6nbkFhl5eSXApjPNjM+TYlDGQYUkxvEgqR8AB60LVgriZVhSdk3PPt55STsaPLEjh2YqsUrZxuU6g7Wr2c6NEcDEyde69Kt3Xajbl5Q3vfELXaz0kNiqE3YHY6nTfN5lPXfHzy9a78qSvO8nzfH8rgAi+wKguCkL1DCcIIoYyI1mEdZnriswrte1i3msZJlDmrA0nSDIXB+iZtMQcrtFyPJ-gEw7KsKGhvDMwG-EEgpSAq3IglgYIQk2cEgPCiJIeyIBcVaPE4kAA)

Comment: Thank you,  I thought it was me going insane, every attempt I made it felt like I was going down the rabbit hole.  I did try the `U extends T` directly on the type, but that had the chicken and egg issue :)